# Matplotlib - The graph does not show in Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, data-science

I just started learning matplotlib. The code I used is here below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,4,6]

plt.plot([x, y])
```

The graph doesn't show up. It just gets stuck. Is there a way to fix it?

I am a beginner matplotlibber, so I'm just following a tutorial, but this doesn't work for me. I just simply want the graph to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing the:

```
plt.show()
```

So your code become:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,4,6]

plt.plot([x, y])
plt.show()
```

Or, if you are using a Jupiter Notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
```